# Send email from HTML page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email

I'm trying to send a mail from a html page using the below:

```
<script>
    function sendMail() {
    var link = "mailto:email@live.co.uk &subject=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText').value)
             + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText2').value)
    ;
    
    window.location.href = link;
}
  </script>


 <!-- Contact Form -->
 <div class="col-md-6 contact">
    <form role="form">
               <!-- Name -->
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <!-- E-Mail -->
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" id="myText">
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                       <!-- Phone Number -->
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <!-- Message Area -->
               <div class="form-group">
                   <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write you message here..." style="height:232px;" id="myText2"></textarea>
               </div>
               <!-- Subtmit Button -->
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-send" onclick="sendMail(); return false">
                   Send message
               </button>
           </form>
 </div>
```

When I press button to click all of the data ends up in the default mail apps "To:" Text input area. Can anyone tell me how to split out the subject and body correctly?? I'd like these to go into the subject and body sections of the email by default.

Comment: `email@live.co.uk &subject=` should be `email@live.co.uk?subject=` - question mark and no space.

Comment: Works perfectly now thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query string variables should start with "?", not "&".

```
var link = "mailto:email@live.co.uk?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText').value)
             + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('myText2').value)
    ;
```

Comment: Works perfectly now thank you! :)